# Use of Awk filter to get the students records details in descending order of total score

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Student details are stored in a file system as follows:

```
Roll_no,name,socre1,score2
101,ABC,50,55
102,XYZ,48,54
103,CWE,42,34
104,ZSE,65,72
105,FGR,31,45
106,QWE,68,45
```

Q.Write the unix command to **display Roll_no and name of the student** whose total score is greater than 100 the student **details are to be displayed sorted in descending order of the total score.**

total score as to be calculated as follows :-

totalscore=score1+score2

file also content the header(Roll_no,name,socre1,score2)

**My solution**:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=",";OFS=" "} {if(NR>1){if($3+$4>100){s[$1]=$2}}} END{for (i in s) {print i,h[i]}}' stu.txt| sort -rk 2n
```

I am not getting how to get sorting according to total score?
please help guys!

***output:-***

```
104 ZSE
106 QWE
101 ABC
102 XYZ
```

Comment: Just for reference: [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add the expected output to the question.

Comment: If you posted the expected output you could have eliminated many misunderstandings...

Comment: ok sir next time I take care of this, i edited the expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following. To keep it simple in calculation(1st get total of numbers for all lines which are greater than `100` Then sort it reverse order by total as per OP then print only first 2 columns by `cut`)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $3+$4>100{print $1,$2,$3+$4}' Input_file |
sort -t, -nr -k3 | 
cut -d',' -f 1-2
```

OR in case you want output in space delimiter in output then try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} $3+$4>100{print $1,$2,$3+$4}' Input_file |
sort -nr -k3 | 
cut -d' ' -f 1-2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $3+$4>100{print $1,$2,$3+$4}' Input_file |   ##Starting awk program setting FS, OFS as comma. Then checking 3rd+4th column sum is greater than 100 then printing 1st, 2nd field along with sum of 3rd and 4th field here. Now passing its output as input to next command.
sort -t, -nr -k3 |                                                  ##Sorting output with setting delimiter as comma and sorting it reverse order witg 3rd column here, sending output as input to next command.
cut -d',' -f 1-2                                                    ##Getting first 2 fields by setting delimiter comma here, to get name and roll number here.
```

---

---

***OR***

```
sort -t, -nr -k3 < <(awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $3+$4>100{print $1,$2,$3+$4}' Input_file) | 
cut -d',' -f 1-2
```

OR in case you need output as space delimited then try following.

```
sort -nr -k3 < <(awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} $3+$4>100{print $1,$2,$3+$4}' Input_file) | 
cut -d' ' -f 1-2
```

Comment: Sir I want output as roll_no name, I mean space between roll_no and name. also I didn't get your  this snippet  "cut -d',' -f 1-2" please elaborate the -f 1-2 option. and one more thing if possible then please use hash table concept.

Comment: @AkshaySingh, I think my output is coming correctly in terms of logic, could you please do lemme know if you are saying about headers not getting printed?

Comment: yes sir, how you rid of this header part in your logic, I didn't get this, moreover your output is right.

Comment: @AkshaySingh, I had mentioned brief explanation in my solution will add detailed one too. I didn't get it you don't want headers in output or you want it?

Comment: @AkshaySingh, No this is NOT printing headers in output, let me add more explanation in my solution now.

Comment: great sir, I got your precise explanation....thanks you so much

Comment: @AkshaySingh, your welcome. Keep learning and keep posting questions, answers on this great site SO cheers :)

Comment: a great answer as usual, strange you was not chosen by @AkshaySingh, you answer before karakfa (also having a good answer anyway)

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS=","} 
       NR==1 {print $0, "total"; next} 
             {if(($5=$3+$4)>100) print | "sort -t, -k5nr"}' file

Roll_no,name,socre1,score2,total
104,ZSE,65,72,137
106,QWE,68,45,113
101,ABC,50,55,105
102,XYZ,48,54,102
```

without header and individual scores

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","} 
       NR>1 && ($3+=$4)>100{print $1,$2,$3}' file | sort -t, -k3nr

104,ZSE,137
106,QWE,113
101,ABC,105
102,XYZ,102
```

or

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","} 
       NR>1 && ($3+=$4)>100 && NF--' file | sort -t, -k3nr

104,ZSE,137
106,QWE,113
101,ABC,105
102,XYZ,102
```

without the final score and not comma delimited

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1 && ($3+=$4)>100 && NF--' file | sort -k3nr | cut -d' ' -f1,2

104 ZSE
106 QWE
101 ABC
102 XYZ
```

reads as written 
if line number is greater than one (skip header) AND
if field 3 + field 4 > 100 (assigned back to field 3) then
if both conditions are satisfied decrement field count so that last field won't be printed.

sort the results based on the third field, 
remove the last field.

Comment: To add a bit of explanation: awk pipes only the relevant part to the sort command. This makes it easy to also include the header into the output. If the header is not requested, the sort command can be moved outside of the awk.

Comment: Sir, I don't want header and score1,score2 and total fields in my output.

Comment: Sir, please add explanation in your fourth solution, I didn't get " NR>1 && ($3+=$4)>100 && NF--" this one...thanks in advance

Comment: yeah, I got your explanation, even little bit complex solution ,but I enjoyed it, thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 0):

you were close:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {if(NR>1){if($3+$4>100){s[$1]=$2}}} END{for (i in s) {print i,s[i]}}' stu.txt| sort -rk 2n
```