# Using awk how to fetch the date day wise?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I'm stuck how to fetch the date in day wise i.e if date is like 03/12/2020 how can I fetch only "03" in awk?
Let's make a scenario using dummy data, file records are given something as follows

```
Cust_id;  orderDate; orderAmt
101; 20/09/2020; 8000
102; 08/08/2020; 6000
103; 03/11/2020; 12000
104; 21-06-2020; 1200
105; 04-07-2020; 1300
```

Possible Output:

```
103; 12000
105; 1300
```

> how can I print the details of customer who bought item in very first
> week in any month using AWK? How to fetch the date field with day wise here. Also
> note that if record like 104 'id', if date format is changed i.e. 21-06-2020
> from default 21/06/2020 how to deal it?

I have tried on stack overflow but didn't get this date situation problem and also tried below link couldn't help me more ?

https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/138974-using-awk-print-date.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding one more variant here, could you please try following written and tested with shown samples. Pass date in `DDMMYYYY` format in `awk`'s variable named `dat` with any dash or slashes and inside it will compare with 2nd field's substring(s) of it.

```
awk -v dat="04072020" '
BEGIN{
  FS="[[:space:]]*;[[:space:]]*"
  OFS="; "
}
dat == (substr($2,1,2) substr($2,4,2) substr($2,7,4)){
  print $1,$3
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v dat="04072020" '              ##Starting awk program from here and creating dat with date of DDMMYYYY format.
BEGIN{                               ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS="[[:space:]]*;[[:space:]]*"     ##Setting field separator spaces(one or more occurrences) semi colon and again one or more occurrences of spaces.
  OFS="; "                           ##Setting output field separator as semi colon space here.
}
dat == (substr($2,1,2) substr($2,4,2) substr($2,7,4)){ 
                                     ##Checking condition if dat is equal to substring of (1st,2nd)chars (4th,5th) and (7th,8th) chars collective sub string.
  print $1,$3                        ##Printing 1st and 3rd fields here.
}
' Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[[:space:]]*;[[:space:]]*"; OFS="; " }
NR == 1 { next }
{ gsub("-","/",$2) }
$2 == tgt { print $1, $3 }
```

```
$ awk -v tgt='03/11/2020' -f tst.awk file
103; 12000

$ awk -v tgt='04/07/2020' -f tst.awk file
105; 1300
```

Comment: Sir Please add comments so I can understand i'm noobie in awk not advanced.

Comment: There's nothing advanced in those 4 lines, it's extremely fundamental awk. Normally you're required to make an attempt at creating a script yourself and THEN we will help you with it. You didn't provide an attempt in your question but now you can look up the constructs used in my answer in the man page or just google a few awk scripts and thereby learn much more than if I spoonfeed you what each line of that script does. Again, this is very, **very** basic awk so it shouldn't take you long. If you do have specific questions **after doing that** then of course feel free to ask.

Comment: Given the awk code you wrote and posted in your previous questions (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62219181/1745001, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62339294/1745001) you should have no trouble at all understanding my much simpler script.

Comment: Sir Thank you for yr suggestions, I'll keep in mind next time, I didn't get the "space" part that you posted inside "FS", because I haven't used that one that is why I asked you.

Comment: You're welcome. It's documented in the man page and many other places as it's not specific to awk- always check the man page and/or the standard and/or just do quick "google" first before asking someone waste time describing things that are already well documented there.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

I assume the OP is referring to purchases within first 7 days of a month.
Form the given input date it looks like the first part is the day, 2nd one is month.
Multiple delimiters can be applied and the second one can be compared with < 7 days.

```
$ cat akshay.txt
Cust_id;  orderDate; orderAmt
101; 20/09/2020; 8000
102; 08/08/2020; 6000
103; 03/11/2020; 12000
104; 21-06-2020; 1200
105; 04-07-2020; 1300
$ awk -F"[-;/ ]+" ' $2<7 ' akshay.txt
103; 03/11/2020; 12000
105; 04-07-2020; 1300
$
```